# Minimum swaping elements in a list to make it same like another list and count the swap in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare-and-swap

I have to list as my input,
a = [0,1,0,1] and
b = [1,0,1,0]

Note: The elements of both list will just 0 and 1.If it's not possible to make both of them same by swap then i will print -1.If it's same in beginning i will print 0 and if it's not same then,
i want to make a == b, In this case, i need 2 minimum swaps.
1st swap will be, 0th index of a and 1st index of a and
2nd swap will be, 2nd index of a and 3rd index of a.
After that a will same as b.

Here is my code:

```
def xx(a,b):
    move = 0
    if a == b:
        print(0)
    else:
        if len(a) == 1 and len(a) == len(b):
            print(-1)
        else:
            for i in range(len(a)):
                if a[i] != b[i]:
                    j = a.index(b[i])
                    a[i] = a[j]
                    move += 1
            count_swap = move // 2
            print(count_swap)
a = list(map(int,input().split()))
b = list(map(int,input().split()))
xx(a,b)
```

Is there any efficient way to get swap count ?

Input:

```
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
```

Output:

```
2
```

Input:

```
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
0
1
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order for swaps to make the lists equal, they must start with the same number of ones and zeros. So we can use a `Counter` to check for impossibility.

And second, a single swap necessarily fixes two differences. So we can just count the differences and divide by 2. We don't actually have to perform any of the swaps.

A demonstration:

```
from collections import Counter

def swap_count(xs, ys):
    if xs == ys:
        return 0
    else:
        cx = Counter(xs)
        cy = Counter(ys)
        if cx == cy:
            n_diffs = sum(x != y for x, y in zip(xs, ys))
            return n_diffs // 2
        else:
            return -1

def main():
    tests = [
        (2, [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]),
        (1, [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]),
        (-1, [0], [1]),
        (0, [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]),
    ]
    for exp, xs, ys in tests:
        n = swap_count(xs, ys)
        print(n == exp, n, xs, ys)

main()
```

Output:

```
True 2 [0, 1, 0, 1] [1, 0, 1, 0]
True 1 [0, 1, 0] [1, 0, 0]
True -1 [0] [1]
True 0 [0, 1, 0, 1] [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be an O(N) solution that iterates over the items and performs the swaps on list b.  If we walk off the end of list b (IndexError) a solution can't be found and return -1.

```
def count_swaps(a, b):
    swaps = 0
    for idx in range(len(a)):
        if a[idx] != b[idx]:
            try:
                b[idx], b[idx + 1] = b[idx + 1], b[idx]
                swaps += 1
            except IndexError:
                return -1

    return swaps


assert count_swaps([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]) == 2
assert count_swaps([0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]) == 1
assert count_swaps([0], [1]) == -1
```